# How to stop a timer in jbpm once it has started?

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

I am timing a flow using intermediate catch timer in jbpm. Once the flow is completed within the duration, I want the timer to stop as well without terminating the entire process . Is there a way we can stop a timer while it has started running either using timer duration or timer cycle based on some variable?

I have tried many things but I am unable to stop the timer by using any condition.